# Cannot Connect Container on Overlay Network: [emerg] invalid host

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-swarm

I am trying to reverse proxy a request through an nginx container in a swarm to a standalone container which shares the same overlay network.

tldr; I receive the following error:

```
2018/03/15 19:00:35 [emerg] 1#1: invalid host in upstream "http://nginx" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:96
nginx: [emerg] invalid host in upstream "http://nginx" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:96
```

The standalone container contains an app which has another nginx frontend:

```
version: "3"
services:
  nginx:
    restart: always
    container_name: my.nginx
    build: ./nginx
    networks:
      - default
      - my-overlay-network
    depends_on:
      - another-service

... other services

networks:
   my-overlay-network:
     external: true
```

I start this app with `docker-compose up -d`.

My swarm contains the reverse proxy:

```
version: "3"
services:
  reverseproxy:
    build: ./reverseproxy
    image: reverse_proxy
    networks:
      - my-overlay-network
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
    deploy:
      replicas: 10
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure

    networks:
      my-overlay-network:
        external: true
```

If I startup the nginx swarm *without* specifying a proxy_pass for the standalone app, I can successfully ping the other host like so:

`ping http://nginx/`

I can confirm the other host receives this request based on the nginx logs.

However, if I specify the docker standalone app in the reverse proxy:

```
upstream standalone {
    server http://nginx/;
}
```

and

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    ... other stuff ...

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://standalone/;
    }
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
2018/03/15 19:00:35 [emerg] 1#1: invalid host in upstream "http://nginx" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:96
nginx: [emerg] invalid host in upstream "http://nginx" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:96
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the syntax for `upstream` is incorrect: it takes a host and port, so it should be:

```
upstream standalone {
    server nginx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `resolver` before upstream:

```
resolver 127.0.0.11;
upstream standalone {
    server http://nginx/;
}
```

`127.0.0.11` is an address of embedded docker DNS server

Comment: hmm... seems I now get this error:

`2018/03/16 01:50:33 [emerg] 1#1: "resolver" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:95
nginx: [emerg] "resolver" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:95`